# log4net: writing a header to each rollover log segment

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I have a RollingFileAppender that rolls over the log file when it reaches a specified file size. This works great.

Is there a way to have log4net insert a header at the top of each newly created log file? Alternatively, is there a way to be notified by log4net when a roll over occurs so that I can write this header myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have to extend an appender or write your own appender for this.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <header value="[Header]&#13;&#10;" />
     <conversionPattern value=" ... " />
</layout>
```

Though it will also write the header if you re-start the application.

Comment: But (from the docs) headers are added at the beginning of a logging session -- not necessarily the beginning of a newly rolled logfile.

Comment: My tests showed that they are written in every file as well. I also looked at the source code and saw that this is the case.

Comment: Is any chance adding pattern strings to the header/footer? For instance `%logger`

Comment: I think this is not supported, but this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2009318/106567

Comment: How can we add %property{hostname} in footer log4net? @StefanEgli

Comment: @Techgeeks1: have a look at the link in my previous comment

Comment: @StefanEgli can you help me in this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228371/can-we-set-the-characters-limited-to-10-characters-in-log4net-property