# Can we set the characters limited to 10 characters in log4net %property?

Tags: exception, logging, properties, log4net, threadcontext

This is my threadContext exception message property

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["excmessage"] = ex.Message;
```

I want to get the first 10 characters of exception message property using log4net.

This is the line in Log4net.config:

```
%property{excmessage}
```

Comment: Not sure if you can do this in the log4net config, but you could do `log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["excmessage"] = ex.Message.Substring(0,Math.Min(ex.Message.Length,10));` Wouldn't recommend it unless you have the full error message logged somewhere else.

Comment: @sgmoore i have full text message in my log but i want it shorter to show this in email.I want it using log4net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you can only "truncate from the beginning" which means you get the end of the string:

```
%.10property{excmessage}
```

Here is a link to the documentation:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html

I suggest that you fill two properties: one with the exception message and the other with the truncated message.