# log4net GlobalContext.Properties set only once

Tags: c#, log4net

I would like to extend my log file with static information, like what OS my software is running.

Is there a way to inject this information only once per file that was created and not for every log entry?

This is how I am doing it currently (but this results in outputting the information over and over again - which isnt necessary since it static information)

```
GlobalContext.Properties["**evInfoOsPlatform**"] = string.Format("OS Platform: {0}", Environment.OSVersion.Platform);

<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level 
                        %logger - %message%newlineOperating System Version: %property{
                        **evInfoOsPlatform**}%newline%exception"/>
</layout>
```

My desired effect would be a logfile looking like this:

```
Static information:
OS Version: Windows 8.1.0101934 32-bit
Culture Info: en-US
Domainname: RandomDomain
Username: Emil
Userrights: Admin      

Messages:
//now all the messages should be printed...
```

This code is used in a C# .Net 4.5 WPF environment.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a RollingFileAppender, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203136/include-header-only-once-at-the-top-of-a-rolling-file) - essentially you want to create a class that inherits from RollingFileAppender and override the `WriteHeader` method to only write the header once to each file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009318/43846) shows the best way to set the Header property, by subclassing `log4net.Layout.PatternLayout`

Putting those together in an example:

```
namespace MyAssembly.log4net.Header.Example
{
    public class HeaderAppender : RollingFileAppender
    {
        protected override void WriteHeader()
        {
            if (LockingModel.AcquireLock().Length == 0)
            {
                base.WriteHeader();
            }
        }
    }

    public class HeaderPatternLayout : PatternLayout
    {
        public override string Header
        {
            get
            {
                StringBuilder headerBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                headerBuilder.AppendLine("Static information");
                headerBuilder.AppendLine("OS Version: "
                          + Environment.OSVersion);
                headerBuilder.AppendLine("Culture Info: "
                          + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                headerBuilder.AppendLine("[Etc] ");
                headerBuilder.AppendLine();
                headerBuilder.AppendLine("Messages:");    

                return headerBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given config like this (you would need to set the assembly names to the correct ones):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
        type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net debug="false">

    <appender name="HeaderAppender" 
              type="MyAssembly.log4net.Header.Example.HeaderAppender,MyAssembly">
      <file value="c:\temp\Test.log"/>
      <layout 
         type="MyAssembly.log4net.Header.Example.HeaderPatternLayout,MyAssembly">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
      <countDirection value="1"/>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="HeaderAppender" />
    </root>

  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

Then this is the resulting log file, complete with header:

```
Static information
OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
Culture Info: en-GB
[Etc] 

Messages:
Info Message
Debug Message
Etc
```